# Remove white spaces unless within quotes, ignoring escaped quotes

Tags: c#, regex

I have a JSON string in which I would like to remove all white spaces that are not within quotes. I searched online and I already found a solution, which is the following:

```
aidstring = Regex.Replace(aidstring, "\\s+(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)", "");
```

However, I am now dealing with a string that contains escaped quotes:

```
"boolean": "k near/3 \"funds private\""
```

and the above regular expression solution turns it into:

```
"boolean":"k near/3 \"fundsprivate\""
```

Since escaped quotes are treated as normal quotes.

Could anyone post a regex in which escaped quotes are ignored?

Comment: My final aim is that I would like the two words funds and private to remain two separate words, and not being stuck together

Comment: I suggest you use a JSON parser to parse the JSON, then reformat it in a compact manner. Using a regex for this sort of thing is going to end up being very complicated.

Comment: Try [`aidstring = Regex.Replace(aidstring, @"(""[^""\\]*(?:\\.[^""\\]*)*"")|\s+", "$1")`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%22%5b%5e%22%5c%5c%5d*(%3f%3a%5c%5c.%5b%5e%22%5c%5c%5d*)*%22)%7c%5cs%2b&i=%22boolean%22%3a+%22k+near%2f3+%5c%22funds+private%5c%22%22&r=%241).

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest using

```
aidstring = Regex.Replace(aidstring, @"(""[^""\\]*(?:\\.[^""\\]*)*"")|\s+", "$1");
```

See [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%22%5B%5E%22%5C%5C%5D%2A(%3F%3A%5C%5C.%5B%5E%22%5C%5C%5D%2A)%2A%22)%7C%5Cs%2B&i=%22boolean%22%3A%20%22k%20near%2F3%20%5C%22funds%20private%5C%22%22&r=%241)

The regex will match all C quoted strings into Capture group 1 and with `$1` these strings will be restored in the result, but all whitespaces caught with `\s+` will be removed.

**Regex explanation**:

*Alternative 1:*

- `("[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*")`:

  - `"` -  a literal `"`
  - `[^"\\]*` - zero or more characters other than `\` or `"`
  - `(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*` - zero or more sequences of...

    - `\\.` - `\` and any character but a newline
    - `[^"\\]*` -  zero or more characters other than `\` or `"`
  - `"` -  a literal `"`

*Alternative 2:*

- `\s+` - 1 or more whitespace (in .NET, any Unicode whitespace)

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought... And this doesn't immediately look legit because there are obvious possible flaws.  But if you think about it, the scenarios where would fail are nearly zero chance of happening:

```
Regex.Replace(aidstring, @"\"\s*:\s*\"", "\":\"");
```

Long story short, look for the spaces you **WANT** to replace, instead of looking for all of the spaces you Don't Want to replace:

```
"boolean"    :    "k near/3 \"funds private\""
         ^^^^^^^^^
```

The only time it would fail is if the actual value-content of the json object were literally a colon... let me know how often that happens.  :)

But Skeet is most-right.  Use a Json Parser to clean it up.